# Trying To Typecast A Node Into A Linked List

Tags: c, casting, linked-list

I have a doubly linked list data structure, and each node within that linked list is another linked list.
I'm trying to typecast the node into a linked list later in the program, but receive the error:

```
error: conversion to non-scalar type requested
```

Which I know is because I'm trying to typecast into a structure which isn't allowed.
What would the work around be for something similar to this?

```
List toPass = (List)(iter->data);
```

I've already tried creating a new List and manually setting all of the values from the iter->data to the structure items but I receive the same error.

Edit: 
Initialize List Function:

```
List initializeList(char* (*printFunction)(void* toBePrinted),void (*deleteFunction)(void* toBeDeleted),int (*compareFunction)(const void* first,const void* second)) {
    List tmpList;

    tmpList.head = NULL;
    tmpList.tail = NULL;
    tmpList.deleteData = deleteFunction;
    tmpList.compare = compareFunction;
    tmpList.printData = printFunction;
    tmpList.length = 0;

    return tmpList;
}
```

Node Function:

```
Node* initializeNode(void* data) {
    Node* tmpNode;

    tmpNode = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));

    if (tmpNode == NULL){
        return NULL;
    }

    tmpNode->data = data;
    tmpNode->previous = NULL;
    tmpNode->next = NULL;

    return tmpNode;
}
```

At this point if you want to test, just make a list of lists, then try to typecast the node into a list.

Edit:

Header structs

List:

```
typedef struct listHead{
    Node* head;
    Node* tail;
    int length;
    void (*deleteData)(void* toBeDeleted);
    int (*compare)(const void* first,const void* second);
    char* (*printData)(void* toBePrinted);
} List;
```

Node:

```
typedef struct listNode{
    void* data;
    struct listNode* previous;
    struct listNode* next;
} Node;
```

Comment: To maximize your chance of getting an answer, your post should contain a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so that someone reading your question can copy/paste the code into an IDE and see that error message. In other words, your question is unlikely to be answered without more code.

Comment: @user3386109 Edited...

Comment: The error is pretty clear, you only have to read it: you cannot sell an apple and call it orange. `Iter->data` is an scalar (your apple) and `List` is a struct (your orange).

Comment: @Pablo I know what the error is... I'm asking what a workaround would be because I have no idea how to typecast the node's data into the linked list. (Which it is a linked list)

Comment: Regardless - in `initializeList` you're declaring `tmpList` on the stack and then returning it as the return value of the function, but this memory is not valid anymore and will result in *unexpected behavior*.

Comment: @SHG I'm not allowed to change the linked list data structure, that was provided by the prof for this specific assignment.

Comment: but what type is `list->data`, you don't show that! If it's a `void` pointer: `List *toPass = list->data;`. If it isn't, then the conversion makes no sense.

Comment: I'm not talking about changing the data structure. As a thumb rule - you cannot allocate memory on the stack inside a function and then use it outside of this function.

Comment: @Pablo edited to show the structs

Comment: you have `void *data`. you should typecast to `List *` type.

Comment: I have a function that I'm trying to pass the typecasted list to that is only allowed to take in a List type. (Not a pointer) Due to this, should I create a function to copy everything from the pointer list to a local list for passing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So if you know that `list->data` is a `void*` pointer pointing to a `List`
object, then you have to do:

```
List *toPass = list->data;
```

no cast is needed because C explicitly casts the `void*`-pointer to a `List*`
pointer.

If you don't want to have a pointer but a copy (bit by bit copy) of the object pointed to by `list->data`, then you would need to
do

```
List toPass = *((List*) list->data);
```

and `toPass` would be a copy of the contents of the object pointed to by
`list->data`.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do like followings,
the typical double linked list implementation:

```
typedef struct list {
    List *prev, *next;
} List;
typedef struct entry {
    List *list;
    List *another link; /* your another dlist here */
    void *my_real_data; /* you store your data here */
    /* ... */
}
```